# Merging two BSTs together in O(max(h1, h2)) time

Tags: algorithm, tree, big-o, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

Is there a way to do this? In other words, is there a way to know which tree has the smaller/larger height without knowing the height themselves? That way we would know which tree we need to pick the room from. Note that all the elements in the first tree are smaller than all the elements in the second tree.

h1 and h2 are the heights of the trees
the height of the merged new tree needs to be max(h1 , h2) + 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the least element from T2 and make it the root of a tree with T1 as the left subtree and the rest of T2 as the right. max(h1, h2) is just a convenient bound on the length of T2's left spine. We can actually get an algorithm that runs in time O(min(h1, h2)) by traversing T1's right spine and T2's left spine in a dovetailed fashion and then executing the appropriate mirror image of this algorithm when the greatest of T1/least of T2 is discovered.

Comment: does this ensure that the height of the new tree is Max(h1, h2) + 1 though..?

Comment: @extremez Yes -- both T1 and the rest of T2 have height at most max(h1, h2), so the height of the whole tree is at most one greater.

Comment: Right, I see it now. I was actually thinking somewhere along this line but  for some reason I kept thinking this would not satisfy the height being max (h1, h2) + 1. Thank you for clearing it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to explicitly find the heights of the trees. Without more specific info, there just isn't anything else you can do. You can find the height of a tree recursively in O(n) time where n is the number of nodes in the tree.